# “cp: cannot create regular file” on a VFAT formatted external USB flash drive

Tags: mount, partition, usb, fstab

I have an external USB drive which is formatted in FAT32. That's the output of the `fdisk -l` command:

```
/dev/sdb1  *       56 15728639 15728584  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

I have the following entry in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=FAF0-4AE6              /media/usb    vfat      defaults,auto,rw,users,nofail,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=1      0         0
```

I am mounting the drive using: `sudo mount -a` but then everything is owned by root:root and I cannot change the ownership of the different directories and to copy files from my internal partition to the external USB drive. It gives me:

```
cp: cannot create regular file ... Permission denied
```

Are my fstab options correct, why I can't use my USB flash drive with regular user's permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vfat partitions don't support file owners/groups. Thus, the Linux kernel has to fake it. By default, it makes root:root own everything. To change this, add `uid=youruser,gid=yourgroup` to the mount options. Then, that user and group will own everything instead.